# Fast Page Refresh Cause Server To Crash For A While

Tags: reactjs, performance, fetch, refresh, webapi

I am using reactjs and ASP.NET WEB API with MSSQL Database.
the thing is, I want to fetch some data when the home page is loaded using useEffect.

In my case its 6 fetches one after the other.
When I run the page everything works fine. I can refresh and get the results again, but there is a bug that when I try to refresh, lets say 10 times, really quickly spamming the <kbd>F5</kbd> button.

The result I get from the server on chrome console is 500 Internal Error, On Postman the error is the connection must be closed.

I just wait about 30 seconds and refresh again, and everything works.
I checked and all the functions in the web API and the connection is closed eventually.

It only happens when I spam refresh. I tried to crash the server using the phone refresh and I just can't - it's not fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed It!
I Will Still Appreciate An Explanation From Someone On Why This Happend.
Thanks.

```js
//Code That Didn't Work
            try
            {
                string ProcedureName = "GetUserById";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcedureName, connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                User user = new User();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    user.UserID = int.Parse(reader["UserID"].ToString());
                    user.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    user.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    user.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
                    user.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                }
                connection.Close();
                if (UserID != user.UserID)
                    throw new Exception();
                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
                throw ex;
            }
```

```js
//The Code That Does Work
try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string ProcedureName = "GetUserById";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ProcedureName, con);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    User user = new User();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        user.UserID = int.Parse(reader["UserID"].ToString());
                        user.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                        user.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                        user.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
                        user.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (UserID != user.UserID)
                        throw new Exception();
                    return user;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```